# Getting key values from list outside dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to calculate a “score” for each key in a dictionary. The values for the key values are in a different list. Simplified example:

I have:

```
Key_values = ['a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4]
My_dict = {'player1': ['a', 'd', 'c'], 'player2': ['b', 'a', 'd']}
```

I want:

```
Scores = ['player1': 8, 'player2': 7]
```

Comment: If that makes things easier, sure

Comment: Please paste valid Python code in your question. Your quotes, for example, are not normal quotes and are considered invalid characters by Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
   score = {}
    key_values  = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
    my_dict = {'player1': ['a', 'c', 'd'], 'player2': ['b', 'a', 'd']}
    scr = 0
    for i in my_dict.keys(): # to get all keys from my_dict
      for j in my_dict[i]: # iterate the value list for key.
        scr += key_values[j]
      score[i] = scr
      scr = 0

    print(score)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create it using a dict comprehension:

```
Key_values = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
My_dict = {'player1': ['a', 'd', 'c'], 'player2': ['b', 'a', 'd']}

scores = {player: sum(Key_values[mark] for mark in marks) for player, marks in My_dict.items()}

print(scores)
# {'player1': 8, 'player2': 7}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```py
>>> Key_values = {"a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c": 3, "d" : 4}
>>> My_dict = {"player1":["a", "d", "c"], "player2":["b", "a", "d"]}
>>> Scores= {k: sum(Key_values.get(v_el, 0) for v_el in v) for k,v in My_dict.items()}
>>> Scores
{'player1': 8, 'player2': 7}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (Updated the syntax in question. key-value pairs are enclosed within curley braces.)

```
Key_values = {‘a’ : 1, ‘b’ : 2, ‘c’: 3, ‘d’ : 4}
My_dict = {‘player1’=[‘a’, ‘d’, ‘c’], ‘player2’=[‘b’, ‘a’, ‘d’]}
Scores = dict()
for key, value in My_dict.items():
  total = 0
  for val in value:
    total += Key_values[val]
  Scores[key] = total


print(Scores)
   # {‘player1’ : 8, ‘player2: 7}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with appropriate `dict` methods and map, should be the fastest among the ones already posted.

```
Key_values = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
My_dict = {'player1': ['a', 'd', 'c'], 'player2': ['b', 'a', 'd']}

new_dict = {key:sum(map(Key_values.get,My_dict[key])) for key in My_dict}
print(new_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'player1': 8, 'player2': 7}
```